# Solving the inequality involving modulus

Tags: inequality

Can I change

$\frac{1}{|x-2|} \le \frac{1}{|2x-3|}$ to $|x-2| ≤ |2x-3| ?
$

If I remembered correctly, I cant change

$a \lt \frac{ 1}{|b|}$ to $a|b| \lt 1$ instead, I have to change it to $a-\frac{1}{|b|} \lt0 $

Is that correct, or my understanding is incorrect?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

The general rule for inverses in  inequalities is this:

> If $a$ and $b$ have the same sign, $\;a<b\iff \dfrac1b<\dfrac1a$.

Comment: Oh.. I was wrong then.. thank you

Answer (score 1):

You are wrong.(Don't try to remember mathematics, you will end up like this!)

Since $|A|$ is always positive, hence multiplying with $|A|$ on both the sides of an inequation **does not** change the inequality .Hence $${1\over |x-2|}\le {1\over |2x-3|}\implies |2x-3|\le|x-2|$$

Comment: Lol I see.. Thanks!